# How can lists know where to insert (efficiently) yet not be able to do random access?

Tags: c++, list

I'm a little confused. Lists are good at inserting in any position, but not good at random access?

(how is it possible that) If you can't do random access, how can you know where to insert?

Likewise, if you can insert at any position, why can't you efficiently read from that position?

Answer (score 4):

If you already have the list node around which you want to insert, insertion is just a matter of allocating a list node and adjusting a few pointers. Of course, if you only know the index at which you want to insert, the lack of random access means you need O(n) time to *get to* that node, even though you only need O(1) additional time to insert after you got there.

Comment: So in other words it is as bad at inserting at random positions as it is at reading at random positions.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm a little confused. Lists are good at inserting in any position,
>   but not good at random access?

True. But it (List) inserts in any position after accessing to that position.
Access order is O(n) and Insertion order is O(1).

> If you can't do random access, how can you know where to insert?

It just inserts in specific places, beginning, ending, or where an iterator indicates.

> if you can insert at any position, why can't you efficiently read from
>   that position?

It can insert in any position after sequential access.

Answer (score 2):

Lists are not good for inserting at any position if you have to hunt for it. They're fast for putting things on the front (and end, if you cache it), and given an already-found iterator in the middle, insertion is fast. So, you're not confused, you just misunderstood what you were told.

Comment: Yeah, the CPP Reference said: "list are specifically designed to be efficient inserting elements in any position, even in the middle of the sequence." That's what threw me off.

Answer (score 1):

**Linked list**

Lists operate using pointers to elements - they can be discontiguous (not in sequence) in memory.

So e.g. a singly linked list would contain pointers as such:

```
head -> element1 -> element2 -> element3 -> NULL
 ^ cur ptr
```

Each element could be defined as a struct:

```
struct Element {
    Element *next;
    int data;
};
```

The *next pointer points to the next element in the list.

Hence, to traverse the list to e.g. ,the last element, you will need to do something like:

```
while (*curNode->next != NULL) {
    *curNode = curNode->next;
}
// curNode after traversing would be last node
curNode->data; // get data in last node
```

The pointer to the last element after traversal would look like this:

```
head -> element1 -> element2 -> element3 -> NULL
                                    ^ cur ptr (3 hops)
```

Hence you would need to do n hops to get to the last node (unless you have a pointer to the last element, aka a "tail" pointer.)

To insert at a certain location, you would hence need to traverse the element until the right slot is found.  In a singly linked list described, it will be O(n).

You can improve the traversal time of the list by using other kinds of lists like e.g. doubly linked list, etc. depending on your needs.  Beware though, that it might be more complex to wire these lists.

**VS array / STL vector:**

data is contiguous in memory.  Hence, to access it, you can simply get the address of first element + index to iterate, and dereference that location.  Hence, you have random instantaneous access.  In this case, the complexity would hence be O(1).